# Dustjs custom filters stopped working

Tags: node.js, dust.js

For some reason my dustjs custom filters have just stopped working on the production server, even though they work fine on my local machine. Anyone have any thoughts as to why this might be happening? I am using dustjs-linkedin v. 2.3.5.

What my filters look like (located in my main server.js file):

```
dust.filters.uppercase = function (value) {
    return String(value).toUpperCase();
};

dust.filters.ucwords = function (value) {
    return String(value).replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
};

dust.filters.money = function (value) {
    return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
};
```

UPDATE: I really need this fixed, and am at a loss as to why this would work locally, but not on my server (this used to work just fine). Unfortunately, I didn't notice when it stopped working and have made MANY updates. Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated.

Here are the app dependencies from my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "socket.io": "0.9.16",
    "dustjs-linkedin": "2.3.x",
    "dustjs-helpers": "1.2.0",
    "consolidate": "0.10.0",
    "mongoose": "3.8.x",
    "node-uuid": "1.4.1",
    "express-form": "0.10.1",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "subdomain": "0.1.0",
    "gm": "1.14.x",
    "connect-mongo": "0.4.1",
    "nodemailer": "0.6.5"
}
```

ANOTHER UPDATE: I have added a console.log('money'); to the money filter and it logs every time it is run locally just fine, but never logs anything to the console on the production end. This leads me to believe that the custom filters are not being added on the production server for some reason.

YET ANOTHER UPDATE: I literally added the filters to the dust source code, and they still wont run on the production server, but work fine locally. Could using NODE_ENV somehow be causing something to mess up in dust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the node_modules directory tree. My guess is you will find two instances of dustjs-linkedin. Your filters will be in one but you are using the other one. Something else is dragging in the other copy based on a different version.

Comment: I do see two instances of dustjs-linkedin:
dustjs-helpers@1.2.0
 - dustjs-linkedin@2.3.5
dustjs-linkedin@2.3.5

How do I fix this?

Comment: I uninstalled dustjs-helpers and reinstalled it and it is now FIXED! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think it happened because you have updated some packages to more recent versions.
I have similiar thing with nodemailer package upgrade from 0.7.1 to 1.0.2 versions
Can you prodive the dependecies hash of package.json file?

Comment: I added the dependencies from my package.json to the question.

Comment: I have double checked all versions running locally and on the production server, and all of the versions match. I don't think this is the issue.